# Reading HtmlHelper data without postback in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, html-helper

I've added a checkbox in cshtml file like this :

```
   @Html.CheckBox("ckShowAll",true)
```

In the same file i need to test if it's checked or not,  I'm stuck here , any idea how can i proceed without doing a postback?

thanks,

Comment: You need javascript/jquery - `var isChecked = $('#ckShowAll').is(':checked');`

Comment: I need to use something like this  
@if ( itschecked ) {
   Write(Html.Raw(@"{name: 'Critical', field: 'Critical', displayName: 'Critical' },"));
    }
so is there a way to not use Javascript ?

Comment: You cannot use Razor for managing events that occur on the client-side, like the click on a checkbox. You need some sort of client-side javascript-based logic.